# PHP: Detecting references in $GLOBALS

Tags: php

I have a simple way to detect references in an array (For debugging purposes)

First I clone the array with `array_values` and then I alter the clone and look for changes in the original. If it's changed that element is a reference.

Short example:

```
<?php

$a = [
    'a' => 'b',
    2 => 3,
];

$b = ['wow'];

$a['ref'] = &$b;

function getrefs($array) {
    $marker = uniqid();
    $copy = array_values($array);
    $i = 0;
    $return = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => &$val) {
        $stash = $val;
        $copy[$i] = $marker;
        if ($val === $marker) {
            $val = $stash;
            $return[] = $key;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $return;
}

var_dump($a);
var_dump(getrefs($a));
```

The problem is that when I try to use this on `$GLOBALS` it's not working, and I can't figure out why. Everything in `$GLOBALS` should be a reference by all rights.

Is `$GLOBALS` just so strange that it's the only array where `array_values` won't correctly copy references?

Comment: You didn't show your attempt with `$GLOBALS`.  Did you try `$GLOBALS['GLOBALS']`?

Comment: No but I just did and it has the same result

Answer (score 1):

It's a possibility that you're not accounting for recursion. The built-in PHP function:

```
var_dump($GLOBALS);
```

Will have the following output

```
array(7) {
   ["_GET"]=>
      array(0) {
   }
   ["_POST"]=>
      array(0) {
   }
   ["_COOKIE"]=>
      array(1) {
      ["PHPSESSID"]=>
      string(26) "od602et6qcfj6pa3pkjtl8go57"
   }
   ["_FILES"]=>
      array(0) {
   }
   ["GLOBALS"]=>
      *RECURSION*
   ["_SESSION"]=>
      &array(0) {
   }
}
```

Comment: Nope that's not it. `$GLOBALS` for some reason is referenced every time it's assigned except when passed through `array_values` (IE: `$a = $GLOBALS;$a['test'] = 1234;` will result in `$GLOBALS['test'] === 1234`, but with array_values it looks like every last reference is broken somehow)